# Why does Chrome add extra html to my page?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a snippet of code that looks like this in my html document:

```
<p style="[some stype]">
    <span style="[some_style]">Request ID : </span>
    <a name="request_id" />
</p>
<p>....</p>
```

When i open it up in Chrome and inspect the `<p>` element, this is what is shown:

```
<p style="[some stype]">
    <span style="[some_style]">Request ID : </span>
    <a name="request_id" />
</p>
<a name="request_id">
    </a>
<p>....</p>
```

It has in fact, added another identical `<a>` tag under the first p.

However, if i select 'view page source', the HTML code shown is identical to that in my file.
Why would Chrome add the extra `<a>` into the HTML?

**Note:** I am aware that `name` is an invalid attribute for an `<a>` however this is how bookmarks are represented in HTML when converting from docx to this format so im sticking with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<a>` is not a self-closing tag. It’s invalid to use `<a />` (instead of `<a></a>`) in HTML (and inadvisable in XHTML for compatibility).

```
<p style="[some style]">
    <span style="[some_style]">Request ID : </span>
    <a name="request_id"></a>
</p>
```

Comment: It says i cant accept your answer until 9 minutes have passed. Thats exactly what i was after. Cheers